# My mySQL call is only returning one value to average where it should be returning all

Tags: mysql, math, median, cumulative-sum

This is my mySQL statement :

```
    SELECT DATE(x.created_at), AVG(TIMEDIFF(y.created_at, x.created_at)/60/60)
    FROM 
        (SELECT *
            FROM events a 
            WHERE a.created_at > '12-10-10 12:12:12'
                AND a.type = 'Started') x INNER JOIN

        (SELECT *
            FROM events a 
            WHERE a.created_at > '12-10-10 12:12:12'
                AND a.type = 'Complete') y ON x.target_id = y.target_id
    GROUP BY DATE(x.created_at)
    ORDER BY DATE(x.created_at)
```

Ideally, I am trying to get a running *median* of every date. So that would be for each date, select the time differences between the `created_at` column, and find the median TIMEDIFF between all the values of that date. And so on, and so forth to each date so long as they have a corresponding `complete`.

As a shorter goal, my above code block is only "averaging" ( since I can't figure out median ), the last returned value of each date, not *all* of them that fall on that date.

Any hints, tips, answers?

Comment: You're grouping by `DAYOFYEAR`, but you're selecting `DATE`... It would also hope if we could see the structure for the `events` table.

Comment: Events table has a `created_at` and `type` column. Also I removed the group by and order by statements and it still will only return the last object.

Comment: Can you create a SQL fiddle for this?  www.sqlfiddle.com

Comment: I would change your group by to DATE(x.created_at).  Either that or change your select to show DAYOFYEAR(x.created_at).

Comment: Hmm.. i updated to reflect `DATE` instead of `DAYOFYEAR` but it still only provides calculations on the last returned object for that Date. Working on a sqlfiddle..

Comment: Not really sure what's going on with SQLfiddle, but I tried to set it up at least.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af67c/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given data suitable for testing, our query seem to work.  Se this corrected SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8458d/3/0

However, the query can be simplified to

```
SELECT DATE(a.created_at),
       AVG(TIMEDIFF(b.created_at, a.created_at)/60/60)
FROM events a
INNER JOIN events b
ON a.target_id = b.target_id
WHERE a.created_at > '2012-10-10 12:12:12'
AND a.type = 'Started'
AND b.created_at > '2012-10-10 12:12:12' -- not needed?
AND b.type = 'Completed'
GROUP BY DATE(a.created_at)
ORDER BY DATE(a.created_at)
```

Comment: @Trip Using data for several days, matching the query, your query seems to give the correct result. In my query, I made a typo (ẁriting `WHERE` instead of `AND` in the probably redundant line). It is fixed now and gives the same result as yours.